# Chrome extensions working in several windows

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with a chrome extension. I want to build an application which will click a button on several subpages. Now I have a script which opens links with users profiles and I need to click INVITE USER on all cards.

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>  
<html>  
    <head><title>Fill</title></head>  
    <body>
        <h2 id="htwo">Button presser</h2>
        <button id="press">Go to activity tab</button>  
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
        <script src="utilities.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
function injectTheScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        // Injects JavaScript code into a page
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "utilities.js"});
    });
}
// adding listener to your button in popup window

document.getElementById('press').addEventListener('click', injectTheScript);
```

utilities.js

```
function goToActivityTab() {      

let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".ludzie");    
for (let i = 0, element; (element = elements[i]); i++) 
   {
       console.log(element);
       element.click();
   }        
}     
goToActivityTab();
```

I suppose that I should create a background script to this application but I can't do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What prevents you from creating a background script?

Comment: I can't do script which will click button and do the same for example x100 in new cards without my click in button in extension many times. This should click button and go to next card with next user and do the same.

Comment: what do you mean? create a background script, which when the button (in popup.html) is pressed, sends signal to all tabs signaling them to click on the needed button (invite user)

Comment: yes. I have for example 40 opened cards and i want to click  button invite if it exist on all cards.